# how to specify static network configuration for dhcp interface & how to check DNS settings for interfaces configured in ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, 16.10, dhcp

I have new ubuntu installation .My network is configured using dhcp.

```
$ ifconfig 
enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::428d:5cff:fe4d:7c4a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 40:8d:5c:4d:7c:4a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 60  bytes 5812 (5.8 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 126  bytes 11851 (11.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Локальная петля (Loopback))
    RX packets 2877  bytes 177223 (177.2 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2877  bytes 177223 (177.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

i tried to specify static configuration for that interface

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp5s0
iface enp5s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

but

```
nmcli device show enp5s0 | grep IP4.DNS
```

prints nothing.

internet is accessible and sites are pinged successfully.

So how to do that?

upd: I've been able to detect that 8.8.8.8 dns is used.

```
host -v www.news.com | grep Received
Received 89 bytes from 8.8.8.8#53 in 56 ms
Received 100 bytes from 8.8.8.8#53 in 101 ms
Received 100 bytes from 8.8.8.8#53 in 98 ms
```

but i don't understand why

```
 nmcli device show enp5s0 | grep IP4.DNS
```

shows nothing.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this `nmcli` command?

Comment: I want it to print DNS server used.

Comment: Presumably, `nmcli` only knows about interfaces which are managed by NetworkManager, but what's the point? Of course the DNS server in use is the one you have configured.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. I needed a tool which showed configuration which is really in use

Comment: In your case `cat \etc\resolv.conf` works; the reason some people use `nmcli` is that NetworkManager does weird things with the DNS if you configure your interface with it.

Comment: Then please edit your question so that it reflects your actual question, *i.e.*, how to check DNS settings for interfaces configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`.